# command object data binding

Tags: grails

I'm trying to use command objects in the following way:

```
class BeneficiaryCommand {
    List<Beneficiary> tempBeneficiaries = org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(), new org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InstantiateFactory(Beneficiary.class))

    static constraints = {
        tempBeneficiaries(validator: {
            it.each{println it.beneficiary} // it.beneficiary is null, but I expect it to have name and address from the form
        })
    }
}

class Beneficiary {
    Contractor beneficiary // Contractor has name and address properties, both non-blank and non-nullable
    Boolean save
}
```

The GSP looks like:

```
<tr class="prop">
    <td valign="top" class="name">
      <label for="beneficiaries"><g:message code="contract.beneficiaries.label" default="New Beneficiary Name" /></label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: i, field: 'name', 'errors')}">
        <g:textField name="tempBeneficiaries[0].name" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="prop">
    <td valign="top" class="name">
      <label for="beneficiaries"><g:message code="contract.beneficiaries.label" default="New Beneficiary Address" /></label>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: i, field: 'address', 'errors')}">
        <g:textField name="tempBeneficiaries[0].address" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="prop">
    <td valign="top" class="name">
        </td>
    <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: beneficiaryCommand, field: 'save', 'errors')}">
        <div id="newBeneficiaryFlagDisplay"><g:checkBox name="tempBeneficiaries[0].save" /> Create new Beneficiary</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `save` property of the command object (represented by the checkbox) is bounded to the command object, but the `name` and `address` are not. I have also tried renaming the text field names to `tempBeneficiaries.beneficiary[0].name` to no avail.

Any ideas on how to capture `name` and `address` into the command object?

Comment: It seems that the `Contractor` instance inside the `Beneficiary` class doesn't get instantiated (the object is `null` and trying `println beneficiary.class` gives `exception: null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the hierarchy of your command object the name of the field should be `tempBeneficiaries[0].beneficiary.name` and `tempBeneficiaries[0].beneficiary.address`

This is the LazyList syntax I've used before to do something similar, but I don't know if your syntax is an issue at all:

```
List<Beneficiary> copies = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Beneficiary))
```

Also, you might try

```
Contractor beneficiary = new Contractor()
```

in your `Beneficiary` class so that an object is available at object creation time to be populated.

Comment: I tried that as well but no luck. `println` in the validator just prints `null`.

Comment: I added a couple of other suggestions you can try.

Comment: `Contractor beneficiary = new Contractor()` did the trick. Thank you very much!