# Grails parent child form validation

Tags: validation, grails, parent-child

I have an Invoice

```
class Invoice{
    static hasMany = [lineItems: InvoiceItem]
    double total
}

class InvoiceItem{
    String description
    double price
    double qty
}
```

My issue is with form validation. If a user enters a string or invalid number format in either price or qty I get a

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String 
to required type double for property price
```

BUT the error is in the Invoice object NOT in the LineItems object therefore I cannot highlight in RED the form appropriately. (And field value remains at zero when displayed so message is somewhat meaningless to user)

I was thinking of using COMMAND object with String parameters and validating their numeric value but I can't figure how to bind the InvoiceItem List.

## What is the appropriate Grails way?

I could do all validation on the client side in javascript but that is not my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with command objects. You need to read:

http://blog.peterdelahunty.com/2009/01/cool-way-to-dynamically-add-entries-to.html

[command object data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394885/command-object-data-binding)

[Grails command object data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677623/grails-command-object-data-binding)

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/validating-nested-command-objects-td1346994.html

Comment: Almost ! lazy list certainly puts me in the right direction but the child items are repeated in the command list. See Grails JIRA GRAILS-9371 http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9371