# grails unknown number of model objects in the view

Tags: grails, model, webforms

Working in Grails 2.2

I have a situation where I need to be able to handle an unknown number of CommitteeMembers in the view. These need to be both created and displayed.

Each one has the usual attributes - name, address, contact information, userid.

I understand that if I name form fields the same name, Grails will return a collection for me to iterate over. In this case, however, I am faced with this situation:

cm_firstname

cm_lastname

cm_address

cm_email

cm_userid

So does this mean I will be given collections of each of these fields? That is not as useful as there is no way to corelate the various firstnames with the correct lastnames, etc.

I am enjoying Grails and am looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: Are you creating a collection of members at a time or is it save one member per submit and show him?

Comment: grails will send them back as an indexed array, so cm_firstname[0] and cm_lastname[0] will belong together, etc.

Comment: I am creating 0 .. n members at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you what I do, which may or may not be the best option. I do this mainly because I don't like data binding.

For your case as an example, I would name my fields: "cm.firstName, cm.lastName, cm.address, cm.email, cm.userId".

If you are in a service:

```
GrailsWebRequest webUtils = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()

List committeeMembers = [].withDefault {new GrailsParameterMap([:], webUtils.getCurrentRequest())}
```

In a controller:

```
List committeeMembers = [].withDefault {new GrailsParameterMap([:], request)}
```

Then

```
params.cm.each { k, v ->
    if (v instanceof String[]) {
        v.eachWithIndex { val, idx ->
            committeeMembers[idx]."$k" = val
        }
    }
    else {
        committeeMembers[0]."$k" = v
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
committeeMembers.each {
    <Create from it.firstName, it.lastName, etc>
}
```

Comment: This is also cool. This uncouples the field names in the form from the field names in the domain class, which is useful.

Comment: I'm going to checkmark this one because I used it, but both answers are reasonable. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Grails Command objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) to do this work for you. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394885/command-object-data-binding) in a SO question. Basically you will have a single collection of `CommitteeMembers` that will be populated in your controller thorugh data binding.

As @Gregg says, in the view you need the fields to have an index.

```
class MyDomain {
  String name
}

class MyDomainCommand {
  List<MyDomain> instances = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(MyDomain))
}

class MyController {
  def save() {
    MyDomainCommand command = new MyDomainCommand()
    bindData(command, params, [include: 'instances'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was coming to this from my comment. :)